# i have a problem in my BroadcastReceiver, after the device is reboot receiver is not called

Tags: android, android-broadcast

my program extends From BroadCastReciever to set Alarm,  after the device is reboot receiver is not called, this is my code

1- BroadcastReceiver

```
public class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction()!=null) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Log.d("myActivity","repooted");
            // alarm settings

        }
    }
}
```

2-xml

```
       <receiver
        android:name=".sync.myReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE"      />
        </intent-filter>


    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml have you added permission to receive boot complete?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: To support direct boot you need to take care of this: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot   Please add android:directBootAware="true" and <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
to receiver

Comment: i added this, but still not working @Ashish Khurange